# Как посчитать количество букв в строке, полученную из другого класса методом get в java 8

Tags: java, массивы, list, потоки-данных, java-stream

Есть List, где написаны имена сотрудников

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

В классе *Employee* есть метод `getName()`, который возвращает имя `return name;`

В классе *Office* нужно написать метод `public Employee getEmployeeWithLongestName()`, который будет выводить работника с наиболее длинным именем при помощи stream. То есть, нужно достать имя из объекта, который добавлен в List, посчитать колличество символов, сравнить с остальными именами и вывести работника, который обладает наиболее длинным именем.

Сижу ломаю голову. Со стримами только начал знакомство.
Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом учебные задания предполагают свое решение, но функционалка - штука нетривиальная, посему самому разобраться бывает достаточно сложно, хотя реализация очень простая:

```
public Employee getEmployeeWithLongestName() {
    return employees.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getName().length())).get();
}
```